# Variable Step Value on Material UI Slider

Tags: material-ui

I have a Material UI slider for choosing a price vlaue that has historically held values between €5 and €100 with a step value of 5, leading to the user being able to choose the following values:

€5, €10, €15, €20, €25, ... etc. ... €95, €100

This has worked fine but now I need to change the starting value from €5 to €1. I can do this but when I do the slider choices behave as follows:

€1, €6, €11, €16, €21, €26, ... etc. ... €96, €100

I need the choices to go up increments of 5 from €5 onwards with the choices being like this:

€1, €5, €10, €15, €20, €25, ... etc. ... €95, €100

So I basically need the step value to be 4 for the first step and then 5 for all steps after that. I can't seem to find a way to achieve this. I want to avoid the slider going up in increments of 1. It needs to go up in increments of 5 from €5 onwards.

Can somebody please help me?

My code is a follows:

```
const marks = [
        {
            value: 1,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "1",
        },
        {
            value: 20,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "20",
        },
        {
            value: 40,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "40",
        },
        {
            value: 60,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "60",
        },
        {
            value: 80,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "80",
        },
        {
            value: 100,
            label: decode(this.state.currencySign) + "100",
        },
    ];

<Slider
    defaultValue={
        this.state
            .price !==
        null
            ? this.state
                  .price
            : this.state
                  .defaultPrice
    }
    valueLabelFormat={
        this
            .valueLabelFormat
    }
    getAriaValueText={
        this.valuetext
    }
    step={5}
    valueLabelDisplay="on"
    marks={marks}
    min={1}
    size="large"
    onChange={(
        _,
        newValue
    ) =>
        this.handlePriceChange(
            newValue
        )
    }
/>
```